# Multiple Lifecycles for one interface with more than one implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, lifecycle

Is it possible with CastleWindsor to configure multiple lifecycles for one interface with more than one implementation?

```
IFoo
```

`FooA : IFoo` **Lifecycle: Singleton**

`FooB : IFoo` **Lifecycle: Transient**

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's currently a bit vague what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's better, but not enough. How do you want to resolve/inject them? Do you want to inject them a `IFoo`? And if so, when should `FooA` be used, and when `FooB`?

Comment: So what's the underlying question? Why are you asking this?

Comment: I only wanted to know if it is possible not how it is possible. For now a case like this never appears and I dont know why someone would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context, my best answer is: use a Proxy:

```
public class FooProxy : IFoo
{
    private readonly FooA a;
    private readonly FooB b;

    public FooProxy(FooA a, FooB b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    void IFoo.SomeFooMethod()
    {
        this.GetFooBasedOnSomeCondition().SomeFooMethod();
    }

    private IFoo GetFooBasedOnSomeCondition()
    {
        return condition ? this.a : this.b;
    }
}
```

This proxy class depends on `FooA` and `FooB` and you can register it as transient to be resolved as `IFoo`.

Another option is to register a delegate factory, that returns the correct implementation:

```
container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>();

container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
    {
        return condition
            ? container.Resolve<FooA>()
            : container.Resolve<FooB>();
    })
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```